# The name 'Dataset1' does not exist in the namespace 'clr-namespace:TC' error

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, visual-studio, xaml

I'm trying to link an data table column to a combobox via binding. The thing is, when I add the data context to the XAML of my file an error reading 'The name 'Dataset1' does not exist in the namespace 'clr-namespace:TC'' shows. 
The program compiles but the combobox remains empty.

Here's the XAML of my file:

```html
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TC"   mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="257" Width="492">
    <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.504,0.498" >
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <local:Dataset1/>
        </Grid.DataContext>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="111*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="373*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="137,34,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding Temps/NA}" />



    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Additionally, this is the .vb file of the same window:

```
    Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System.Windows.Controls
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Namespace TC

    Public MustInherit Class MainWindow

        Inherits System.Windows.Window

        Private Sub ComboBox_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs)

        End Sub
    End Class

End Namespace
```

I haven't added anything to it since I'm not sure what is missing. I'm running VS 2013 on Parallels desktop on a Macbook Pro 2014.

The dataset which I'm trying to set as the data context is in the same project as the XAML above. Is there anything missing on the XAML or on the .vb file?

Comment: Are you sure is Dataset1 and not DataSet1?

Comment: Yes, the name is "Dataset1.xsd"

Comment: Check the namespace of the generated dataset

Comment: It's strange I've just added an empty DataSet to a dummy project and the default name was DataSet1.xsd, did you change the S to s ?

Comment: Yup, already checked and the name is Dataset1.xsd.

The weird thing is, the compiler apparently IS recognizing "dataset1" as being set as the data context, since when I click on the combobox and change its ItemSource it shows "The data context is set to Dataset1" and let's me choose the column I want to bind. The problem is when I try to compile. It shows the same "The tag Dataset1 does not exist in XML namespace" message. I already tried changing the debug mode to x86 and rebuilding/restarting VS.